# How to create a custom apache Spark scheduler?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, scalability, scheduler, distributed-computing

I have a p2p mesh network of nodes. It has its own balancing and given a task `T` can reliably execute it (if one node fails another will continue). My mesh network has Java and Python apis. I wonder what are the steps needed to make Spark call my API to lunch tasks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oh boy, that's a really broad question, but I agree with Daniel. If you *really* want to do this, you could first start with:

1. [Scheduler Backends](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-apache-spark/content/spark-scheduler-backends.html), which states things like:

   > Being a scheduler backend in Spark assumes a Apache Mesos-like model in which "an application" gets **resource offers** as machines
   >   become available and can launch tasks on them. Once a scheduler
   >   backend obtains the resource allocation, it can start executors.
2. [TaskScheduler](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-apache-spark/content/spark-taskscheduler.html), since you need to understand how tasks are meant
   to be scheduled to build a scheduler, which mentions things like
   this:

   > A TaskScheduler gets sets of tasks (as TaskSets) submitted to it from the DAGScheduler for each stage, and is responsible for sending
   >   the tasks to the cluster, running them, retrying if there are
   >   failures, and mitigating stragglers.

   An important concept here is the Dependency Acyclic Graph (GDA),
   where you can take a look at its GitHub [page](https://github.com/Microsoft-MNR/GDA/tree/master/src/main/java/org/apache/spark).

   You can also read
   [What is the difference between FAILED AND ERROR in spark application states](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39172115/what-is-the-difference-between-failed-and-error-in-spark-application-states) to get an intuition.
3. [Spark Listeners — Intercepting Events from Spark](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-apache-spark/content/spark-SparkListener.html)  can also come
   in handy:

   > Spark Listeners intercept events from the Spark scheduler that are emitted over the course of execution of Spark applications.

   You could take first the [Exercise: Developing Custom SparkListener
   to monitor DAGScheduler in Scala](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-apache-spark/content/exercises/spark-exercise-custom-scheduler-listener.html) to check your understanding.

In general, [Mastering Apache Spark 2.0](https://www.gitbook.com/book/jaceklaskowski/mastering-apache-spark/details) seems to have plenty of resources, but I will not list more here.

---

Then, you have to meet the Final Boss in this game, Spark's Scheduler GitHub [page](https://github.com/apache/spark/tree/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/scheduler) and get the feel. Hopefully, all this will be enough to get you started! :)

Answer (score 2):

1. Take a look at how existing schedulers (YARN and Mesos) are implemented.
2. Implement the scheduler for your system.
3. Contribute your changes to the Apache Spark project.